# Selenium Webdriver Failed to decode response from marionette error while trying to turn to a new page

Tags: python, selenium

I use Selenium 3.6.1 and Firefox 55.0/57.0 with Python 2.7.When I use the function`driver.get(page_URL)`,several page can be opened normally but there are one page will get this error message:

```
   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

And all of the following pages cannot be acquired and got the same error.My geckodriver version is v0.19.0,which should be fittest to Firefox 55.0,but it still doesn't work.Is there any way I can solve this?